# OnBeginStreaming(Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioTrack, Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioStreamer)': no suitable method found to override

Tags: windows-phone-8, shoutcast

I have written the following code for playing shoutcast urls in windows phone 8.(based on a post in stackoverflow)

```
namespace PhoneApp1
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
     private ShoutcastMediaStreamSource source;


     public MainPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
     private static List<AudioTrack> _playList = new List<AudioTrack>
{
    new AudioTrack(null, "Radio Name", "Music Name", null, null),
};

  protected override void OnBeginStreaming(AudioTrack track, AudioStreamer streamer)
     {
        ShoutcastMediaStreamSource source = new ShoutcastMediaStreamSource(new Uri("http://38.101.195.5:8956",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        streamer.SetSource(source);
     }
```

But it was not working and an error was raising

Error :'PhoneApp1.MainPage.OnBeginStreaming(Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioTrack, Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioStreamer)': no suitable method found to override.

Do we have any method to play shoutcast radio urls in windows phone 8.
 I have googled a lot even though did not find any method for streaming shoutcast urls.

Can anybody please tell me how can I rectify this error and play shoutcast urls in windows phone 8.Working on this app from many days...
Many thanks in advance..

Comment: You should Bing instead ;-). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh394039(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Bing?Sorry I did not get you.I have used Background Player many times but no use...Many Thanks...